# Making logging of arrays in syslog readable

Tags: php, syslog, rsyslog

For troubleshooting, I often wish to log arrays and/or objects and use something like `syslog(LOG_INFO,'cmds: '.print_r($cmds_reply,1));` which produces the following output.  My difficulty is reading the log with all the superfluous characters and whitespace. Is there a better way?

```
Nov  3 14:38:19 raspberrypi php: cmds: Array#012(#012    [46] => Array#012        (#012            [0] => sv#012            [1] => stdClass Object#012                (#012                    [name] => to#012                    [value] => 5#012                )#012#012        )#012#012)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [array_walk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and a custom printing function?

Comment: Yea, maybe so.  Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Update your `~/.bash_rc` and append this:

```
function stail { tail "$@" | perl -pe 's/#([0-7]{3})/chr oct $1/ge'; }
export -f stail
```

`source ~/.bash_rc`

Then you can do:

`stail -f <path to your log>`

You will see your log in a more human readable form.